# How can i push data elements to two array at same time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `$scope.event` where i am pushing data when i received from a server , I am working with the angularjs progress-bar so based on user interaction i want to start recording data so when data start recording i want to create new array like `$scope.progressbarData` so i can set dynamic value of the progressbar.

ctrl.js

```
 $scope.event = [];
 $scope.progressbarData = [];
 $scope.dynamic = 0;
    $scope.max = 200;
    socket.on('ditConsumer',function (data) {
        var obj = {
            file:$scope.filename,
            data:data
        }
        $scope.event.push(data);
        if(sendMessageFlag === true) {
            $scope.dynamic = $scope.event.length;
           return  sendMessageToFile(obj);

        }
    });
```

main.html

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <uib-progressbar max="max" animate="true" value="dynamic">{{dynamic}} / {{max}}</uib-progressbar>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add another Array.push()? Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I was looking for any other solution , but for now i will go with this approach array.push. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Any other solution would likely obscure logic from the reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add another Array.push() inside your event handler. This is readable and is nothing short of the standard approach in this situation.

```
$scope.event = [];
 $scope.progressbarData = [];
 $scope.dynamic = 0;
    $scope.max = 200;
    socket.on('ditConsumer',function (data) {
        var obj = {
            file:$scope.filename,
            data:data
        }
        $scope.event.push(data);
        $scope.progressbarData.push(data);
        if(sendMessageFlag === true) {
            $scope.dynamic = $scope.event.length;
           return  sendMessageToFile(obj);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks that make sense!